# How to assign a value selected from a Picker to a variable in another class?

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

I would like to use a picker to select a value and store that value in a variable contained in another class. How can I do that? Here is my code:

my contentview

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State public var selectedOperator = ""
    @ObservedObject var bitwiseCalculator = BitwiseCalculator()
    
    let operators = ["AND", "OR", "XOR"]
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Picker("Operator", selection: $selectedOperator) {
                    ForEach(operators, id: \.self) { op in
                        Text(op)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

and the variable in the class where I want to save it

```
class BitwiseCalculator: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var bitwiseOperator = ""
    
}
```

Comment: Use `$bitwiseCalculator.bitwiseOperator` & switch your `@ObservedObject` to `@StateObject`

Comment: Thanks for helping. It worked.

Comment: You also may want to make your operators be an enum, so you have a defined set to choose from.

Comment: Im glad it worked. Do you mind accepting the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
$bitwiseCalculator.bitwiseOperator
```

& switch your

```
@ObservedObject to @StateObject
```